# Put div to the bottom of parent without absolute

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is:

HTML

```
<footer>
   <!-- ... -->
   <span class="copyright">abc</span>
</footer>
```

CSS (sass)

```
footer {
  // ...

  text-align: center;

    > .copyright {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }       

}
```

So simply to pull the copyrigh down to the bottom of the parent block and center it. It's pretty easy using `position: absolute`, however, the centering the way using `display: inline-block` on the child element and `text-align: center` on the parent element wouldn't work then.

Is it possible to put the copyright down while keeping it *relative*?

Comment: want to use javascript/jquery?

Comment: I'd really like to solve it in a CSS way, if possible

Comment: try display: table-footer-group

Answer (score 9):

Flexbox can do that if the height of the parent is defined or resolvable.

[*Complete* Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vLqrvO)

```css
footer {
  height: 150px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  background: plum;
}
.copyright {
  margin-top: auto;
  /* push to bottom */
  background: red;
  align-self: flex-start;
  /* collapse to own width */
  margin-left: auto;
  /* centering */
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <header>I'm a header</header>

  <span class="copyright">Copyright</span>
</footer>
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complex solution on simple problem. Only real placing can be done with absolute positioning or Javascript.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wocfpcdu/ What if I want to add two 50% columns to the footer?

Comment: That's not what is asked for. What does columns have to do with this?

Comment: I am just trying to tell you that your solution is just a variation of mine. Except more complex and affects all elements in the footer. Check the spans: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrqyVX - I always prefer simplicity over complexity

Comment: No It's not a variation of your **at all**. It's an *entirely* different layout method. Adding padding is **not** putting the copyright at the bottom of the footer. - See https://jsfiddle.net/u0oL5a2k/2/

Comment: On given question it is a variation. You are just talking semantics. On screen your solution works as well.

Comment: But I can really see your point. However, me/you have no idea how the solution is used. I do not think a good solution affects all other elements in footer that are not in the question. Matter of opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Although I agree flexbox can be used, its browser support is not awesome on IE ([Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)).

I would use just simple block with text-centering.
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0oL5a2k/)

Here it is in simplicity:

```
footer {
    border: 1px solid #900;
}

footer > .copyright {
    padding: 50px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you really need to use inline-block, add this to copyright CSS:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: This is not *placing* the element at the bottom of the div...it's just adding extra space above it pushing everything else away. - https://jsfiddle.net/u0oL5a2k/1/

Comment: Your solution is no different. It just changes all elements to equivalent to width 100% and inserts float. IE you cannot have anymore two items next to each other: https://jsfiddle.net/1adb0aLL/

Comment: If anything, you affected more possible elements in the footer than necessary and overcomplicated the solution.

Comment: I suggest you check again..the complete solution (which I have added) does not have 100% width.